# Disappearing desktop icons

Tags: windows-7, backup, icons

Every now & then an icon or two will just disappear. I have vision scanning problems so I keep 134 icons on my desktop in a specific order so I can find them. If an icon comes to mind I know where to find it, but if one disappears, I don't know which one it was, only that there is now a blank space in the middle of my icon group.

I want to save all of my icons as they are on my desktop & save them to a USB memory stick so I can have an external back up. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding backup, have you tried simply copy the shortcuts to your USB stick?

Comment: Not a true fix - Once you have the icons set the way you want them, screen shot the desktop. If one disappears you know what to replace.

Comment: It should be easy to use your sync program of choice and sync .lnk files within `User Profile/Desktop.  Do it once then change the direction to only allow the flash drive to update the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Request and install this hotfix:

**Broken shortcuts are deleted from the desktop in Windows 7**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2642357/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Per your question of how to save desktop icons and positions and save them to a memory stick:

Try Desktop Restore.

---

Reading your entire question though, you may be happier using a application such as [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) which separates shortcuts, files, folders into categories based on how you want them.

---

Maybe somebody else knows the fix for the issue Windows is having, or reinstalling Windows may be the best option.